# Alt+F2 then "poweroff" not working in Unity (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, shutdown

I come from Fedora 16-20 and definitely freshman in using Ubuntu, I was used in Gnome3 to turn off my computer by typing ALT+F2, then typing "poweroff" and return.

In Unity "ALT+F2" actually open the "quick terminal" but "poweroff" command is not working, as well as any other poweruser command (launching applications seems fine), even if provided with sudo command (it is not asking any password).

From the shell it is working fine ("sudo poweroff" and inserting the password).

I've read that it is possible to define a shortcut for this, but I'm not interested in (in that case I can simply use the GUI), **I only want to know if it is possible to use poweroff from the "quick terminal" (ALT+F2), or if it is not available for some reason** (**and possibly** I would undestand **why**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because 'sudo' reads input from the Terminal. Alt+F2 doesn't provide a terminal.

To get poweroff (and other admin tools) to work in Alt+F2, use this:

1. First, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```

   (It may be already installed in older versions of Ubuntu)
2. You can then use 'gksu' instead of 'sudo' in the Alt+F2 launcher.

Comment: Thanks minerz029, I was not aware of gksu (it was already installed and solved the problem). My last doubt is why on Fedora "poweroff" never required sudo (neither from Alt+F2, nor in the terminal), while on Ubuntu it is asking in both cases.

Comment: @Alessandro Fedora likely has its permissions setup differently or you may be logged in as root.

Comment: No I always run Linux using a nonprivileged user (sudoers), probably it is the first option you mentioned, I will dig into it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use Synapse
it can expect and suggest command or program you want to run while you typing 
go to packages.ubuntu website and search for [ synapse ] , install it , and enjoy

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu! type shu? perhaps you could edit and improve this answer. providing more details regarding the package you suggest installing might help. As it is this is a link only answer and is likely to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

try CTRL-ALT-T instead

`sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo shutdown -P now` to power off immediately. see `man shutdown` for more detail and options.